# How to test a2212/13t 1000kv?

Tags: motor

I have got a a2212/13t 1000kv brush less motor in a quadcopter which is running the propeller. I have to use that then how can I know that those motors are working?

Comment: Are you sure of your data? Is that "1000kv" part of the model number or does it really means 1000kV of voltage? I find it unreasonable, unless it is an isolation voltage of some kind, not the working voltage of your motor.

Comment: Even if it is a typo and it is meant to be 1000kW (power) it seems fairly unreasonable for a quadcopter (1MW?!?).

Comment: A link to some sort of datasheet/spec sheet would be welcome.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati I see you are not familiar with [BLDC motors](http://www.flyelectric.com/ans.kv.html).

Comment: There should be a way way to put the controller into a mode where it will test the motor. I built a quadcopter a few years ago, and I was able to do that but I don't remember the details. Oh, and maybe this is obvious, but when you test it, do so without a propeller at first. Once you are sure everything is working you can put the propellers on.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Thanks for the info! You are definitely right. I stand corrected. Very unusual way to specify a characteristic constant, though. Anyway, you always find cryptic ways to specify things in any field of engineering. Oh, well, you always learn something new here on EE.SE :-) I won't remove my comments, so that they will act as a caveat to anyone making the same mistake as myself.

Comment: The market has decided that "1000kv" is acceptable shorthand for "Kv (velocity constant) = 1000rpm/volt" or better, "105 radians/sec/volt"

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of finding out if a BLDC motor works.

- Try to rotate the shaft of the motor. If it's stuck, then it's a good chance there's something inside the motor that shouldn't be there.
- Measure the **inductance** from wire A to B, wire B to C, wire A to C. Their values should be roughly the same. The reason for why it's pointless to measure the resistance is because it's usually around 0.1 Ω which is something you can't really differentiate with a cheap multimeter.
   "Oh, all wirings are 0.1 Ω, this tells me nothing". 
  "Oh, 0.1 mH there, 0.1 mH here, 1 µH here, okay there's a short here, this motor is broken".
- Use your ESC (**E**lectronic **S**peed **C**ontrol) that you are going to use with the motor.  If you are having problems with generating the pulses that the ESC needs. Then generate them with a MCU (**M**icro**c**ontroller **U**nit). Use no load first, so take off the propeller. Start slow and go up until you see it spin. If it never spins then there is a big chance that it's broken. Or the ESC is bad. Or that wherever you are getting your power from, is not delivering enough.

With just those three tests you will find out if it's working or not.

---

If you want to test it more thoroughly then you can always make a 3 phase motor driver from 6 transistors.

[image]

Source: http://www.irf.com/electronics/topology-fundamentals

These are IGBT's, you don't *have* to use them, you can also use MOSFET's. If you are going to use BJT's then you will want to add diodes in parallel with the BJT's. Efficiency wise, IGBT (If you will use large currents, say above 100 A) > MOSFET > BJT. But for a test setup then it doesn't really matter.

For a test, you will most likely just want to use a duty-cycle in the 1-10% regions, otherwise you will probably fry your transistors, because for a test-setup you won't use high end MOSFET's I assume. And yet again, the signals required to drive the MOSFET's should originate from a MCU, or a ring oscillator + buck converter.

If you want to actually build one then either ask another question regarding that (show where you're stuck, we won't help you if you haven't done any effort)), or google it.